# Using generatedvalue from parent entity

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have two entities in our project using Doctrine:

```
class User
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $user_id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="UserProfile", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="user_id", unique=true)
     * @var UserProfile
     */
    private $profile;

    //...
}

class UserProfile
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="user_id")
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $user_id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $first_name = '';

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
     private $last_name = '';

     //...
}
```

And I am trying to generate new rows in the DB by using something like:

```
$user = new User();
$user->setUsername('test');
$user->setEmail('test@example.com');
$user->setPassword(password_hash('password', PASSWORD_BCRYPT));

$em->persist($user);
$em->flush();

$userProfile = new UserProfile();
$userProfile->setFirstName('test');
$userProfile->setLastName('user');

$user->setProfile($userProfile);

$em->persist($user);
$em->flush();
```

Which seems similar to the example here:
https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/tutorials/composite-primary-keys.html#use-case-2-simple-derived-identity

This throws an error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Doctrine\ORM\ORMException: Entity of type
>   App\Entity\UserProfile is missing an assigned ID for field 'user'. The
>   identifier generation strategy for this entity requires the ID field
>   to be populated before EntityManager#persist() is called. If you want
>   automatically generated identifiers instead you need to adjust the
>   metadata mapping accordingly. in
>   /home/site/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/ORMException.php on
>   line 87

If I add a User without a UserProfile this works fine and I get a row in the database with user_id being generated from the MySQL auto increment. How can I get UserProfile to use the newly created user_id when creating a new profile?

Am I over complicating things with the association? Should I just create a setUserId() method on the UserProfile?

Comment: Can you post the code for the function `User::setProfile()`?

Comment: It's nothing special:

`public function setProfile(UserProfile $profile) : self
{
 $this->profile = $profile;

 return $this;
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @emix and @fubar, both helped contribute to the solution. This is what worked in the end:

```
class User
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $user_id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="UserProfile", mappedBy="user", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @var UserProfile
     */
    private $profile;

    //...

    public function setProfile(UserProfile $profile) : self
    {
        $profile->setUser($this);

        $this->profile = $profile;

        return $this;
    }
}

class UserProfile
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="profile")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="user_id")
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $first_name = '';

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
     private $last_name = '';

     //...
}
```

Which involved removing `$user_id` from the `UserProfile` entity and adding an inversedBy parameter to the OneToOne.

Removing `JoinColumn` from the `User` entity and fixing the setter for `setProfile()` so it sets `$user` on the UserProfile entity.

Answer (score 1):

The relationship between the `User` and `UserProfile` entities is persisted on the `UserProfile::user` property, however, when you're calling `User::setProfile()`, you're not setting that property.

Change your `User::setProfile()` function to the following:

```
function setProfile(UserProfile $profile): self
{
    $profile->setUser($this);
    $this->profile = $profile;

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it results in a similar error although now it complains: `UserProfile is missing an assigned ID for field 'user_id'. The identifier generation strategy for this entity requires the ID field to be populated before EntityManager#persist() is called. If you want automatically generated identifiers instead you need to adjust the metadata mapping accordingly. in /home/ddc/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/ORMException.php on line 87`

Comment: In your code, you're calling `$em->persist($user);` twice, rather than `$em->persist($userProfile);`

Comment: Changing it to `$em->persist($userProfile);` doesn't change the error. The association should cascade from user -> userProfile anyway.

Comment: Have you validated your relationships?

Comment: I just ran `orm:validate-schema` and it complained about me having the `$user` field in `UserProfile` as an id. I removed that and the tool validated. The same error is thrown though.

Comment: Do you have an ID column on your `UserProfile` entity? Can you post your updated code? Because the annotations on the `$user_id` and `$user` properties look wrong. They have `@ORM\Id` annotations, which is wrong.

Comment: I removed `@ORM\Id` from the `$user` property. I don't have a separate id column on that table, just a unique index on the `user_id` column.

Answer (score 1):

Your mapping is invalid. Validate your schema - missing `mappedBy` and `inversedBy`. When you fix the mapping this will work as expected.

Validating schema in Symfony:

```
bin/console doc:sch:val
```

In ZF:

```
php public/index.php orm:schema-tool:validate
```

Comment: `./vendor/bin/doctrine orm:validate-schema` says it's correct (I'm not using a framework). Also the example on the doctrine site doesn't mention mappedBy or inversedBy. I have tried adding those previously, but it didn't help.

Comment: There's something wrong with your schema anyway. Why do you need that `$user_id` property in both entities, as a part of the `Id` lol? It doesn't make any sense. Keep only the `$profile` in the `User` entity, the `$user` in the `UserProfile` entity and link them together using `inversedBy` on the user and `mappedBy` on the profile. Drop unnecessary `$user_id` property from both entities. You also don't need the "unique" setting when using the `OneToOne` relations as it is set by default. Fix your mapping, update your question then we can continue. Don't think about the database, focus on model